# Geoserver - layer from sql server

Tags: geoserver

I am new to Geoserver (version 2.4.3). I have configured SQL store and then tried to create a Layer over one of my views with the correct coordinate system, when I tried to preview the layer using openlayers -  I got this error in the logs.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:610)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:563)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:165)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1493)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:775)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerStatement.java:611)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureReader.<init>(JDBCFeatureReader.java:140)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:580)
    ... 110 more
2013-12-29 12:49:52,626 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2013-12-29 12:49:52,632 ERROR [geotools.rendering] - Error querying layer
java.lang.Exception: Error transforming bbox
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1068)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2009)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:837)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:481)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:251)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceM
```

Comment: `Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.` seems to be the crux of it. Does the layer have a funny name? Or strange column name? Do other layers work?

Comment: it seems that i have used geographic types and i found the geoserver dont use geographic but geometric

Comment: If that's the answer then feel free to Answer your question with that (this is just a comment).